# How to scroll item in the Menu setting effectively?

Tags: menus, menu-order

My menu list is so long. If I want to move an item to the top of the list, I need to hold and scroll all the way up. This is inefficient and annoying. Is there any way to improve this process?

[image]

Comment: For now, I could only say, this is a good question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the only issue is that you want to move an item to the top, there is actually a link to achieve this, once you have clicked to expand on a single menu item

[image]